# blog.html does not open with Live Server using Visual Studio Code

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, liveserver

I'm trying to learn HTML, and I have a problem. When I try open my blog.html with live server I get an error code saying 'Cannot GET /blog.html/'.

I am not sure why, since my index.html page opens fine with live server.
I cannot include pictures, but inside my main folder for the website, I have index.html, blog.html and a folder for images.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes Live Server doesn't save files to the server.

Try restarting VS Code or editing the file and then saving, and then try again.